# How to setup Easystroke so that the strokes work outside of the Easystroke window?

Tags: firefox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have setup Easystroke to start Firefox with a simple mouse gesture, the only issue is the gesture will only work when I have Easystroke open and I do the gesture INSIDE the window. If i click hide or minimize or close Easystroke program, the gesture no longer works. I can see the red line when I try to make the gesture but it doesn’t open Firefox. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Original answer:

It won't work outside of Firefox. There is easystroke application in Ubuntu repo that lets you use system wide gestures.

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

For more info check out [this link](http://www.maketecheasier.com/add-mouse-gestures-to-linux/).

## What worked for OP:

1. In your home directory: rename `.easystroke` directory to `.easystroke.bak` in order to remove and backup all its previous settings and actions.
2. Reboot.
3. (If everything already works fine, then you can stop here).
4. Open Easystroke app.
5. In the preferences tab: uncheck the option "Show tray icon".
6. Reboot.

Comment: You have read incorrectly. I have easystroke installed. i have it setup to open firefox with a stroke. It will only work with EASYSTROKE open and when the stroke is done INSIDE the easystroke window. I can have firefox closed completely and easystroke window open and have it open firefox. but when I have easystroke window hidden or closed i cannot open firefox with the same gesture. and Yes easystroke is added to my startup apps. and if you scroll to the bottom of that URL you provided i have already posted there as well..

Comment: I thought you used firefox gesture plugin. I have been using easystroke for two years, most of the time I use it, it works perfectly. You might  not set up it correctly.

Comment: I set right button for gesture recognition.

Comment: I had it set to use "Shift+left" button. and as i said it works when im inside the easystroke application window. I will try with the right button and see what i get and repost accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Setting it to right button did not improve anything. program still only opens firefox if i am inside the easystroke window. Hmmm

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your situation. Maybe you checked a tick in the settings

Comment: in Advanced tab; there is a tick saying `only enable easystroke for applications listed in actions tab` is it unchecked?

Comment: Yes it is unchecked. i even removed easystroke completely and reinstalled and tried a fresh instal in case something happened during install but it made no difference.

Comment: try to delete `~/.easystroke` directory `rm -R -i /home/$USER/.easystroke` and restart easystroke.

Comment: deleted and restarted. still unable to. Dont understand why it would only work inside the window.

Comment: In preferences tab uncheck `show popups` and `show tray icon`

Comment: Ok so i just rebooted after i did deleted that directory as you said and unchecked show tray icon which was check and upon reboot i had to readd my gesture to open firefox and it now works! thank  you for your help kenn!

Comment: glad it works. You are welcome